# Not select first row of datagridview

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm loading a datagridview using the BGW component. I'm trying to NOT select the first row of my DG. I try with these two lines of code, but it does not work.

```
DG.ClearSelection()
DG.CurrentRow.Selected = False
```

I use both on the load event of the form and in the event RunWorkerCompleted of the BGW.

Any suggestions?

The DG´s properties that I assign are  FullRowSelect and AutoGenerateColumns to False ..

thanks

Comment: Do you want Column headers to appear?

Comment: have you tried to assign current cell ?